# Where do I get pythonnet for python 3.3?

Tags: python-3.3, win32-process, python.net

I cannot find pythonnet for python 3.3. All I found is for python 2.7. Please help me, and send me link (for win32 application).

Comment: could you provide more links to this module and the links you used?

Comment: I am looking for Python.NET for Python 3.x as well and came across your question. If you found pre-compiled builds, any chance you remember where or if you ended up compiling your own build?

Answer (score 2):

I found two self-made forks which should work under Python 3.x:

https://github.com/renshawbay/pythonnet

https://github.com/tonyroberts/pythonnet

Both "only" provide sources and must be compiled, didn't have time yet to test...